# How do I set my player model to a Taunt position while I am not actualy Taunting?

Tags: team-fortress-2

Sometimes on random servers, I see player stuck in the Conga animation while moving, jumping, and attacking normaly. How do I get this to happen, and if so, is there a way to do it consitantly?

I have seen this for Conga, High Five, Flipping Awesome, Rock Paper Scissors, and Skullcracker.

Answer (score 3):

It's surprisingly easy: Simply start taunting at the end of the round (i.e. the victory period where everyone has crits) and keep going until the round ends. you will spawn when the next round starts in the conga pose, but will still be able to move and use your weapons. Also, you won't be able to tell whether or not it's working because the HUD will appear to be the same as usual. You will need a friend or someone on the server to tell you if it's working or not.

Comment: What causes it to cancel?

Comment: @ShadowZ. Taunting usually stops it, but it can sometimes end on death

Comment: There has to be another way, in round. I saw a Soldier jump into the air and while he landed, started to Conga, but still move normaly.